# Syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, rm

When I use below code in Ubuntu terminal, it works fine:

```
rm !(*.sh) -rf
```

But if I place the same line code in a shell script (clean.sh) and run the shell script from terminal, it throws an error:

clean.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm !(*.sh) -rf
```

The error I get:

```
./clean.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./clean.sh: line 2: `rm !(*.sh) -rf'
```

can you help?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/220104/13792

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`rm !(*.sh)` is a `extglob` syntax which means remove all files except the ones that have the `.sh` extension.

In your interactive `bash` instance, the shell option `extglob` is on :

```
$ shopt extglob 
extglob         on
```

Now as your script is running in a subshell, you need to enable `extglob` by adding this at the start of the script :

```
shopt -s extglob
```

So your script looks like :

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
rm -rf -- !(*.sh)
```

**EDIT :**

To remove all files except `.sh` extension ones use `GLOBIGNORE` (as you don't want to enable `extglob`) :

```
#!/bin/bash
GLOBIGNORE='*.sh'
rm -rf *
```

**Example :**

```
$ ls -1
barbar
bar.sh
egg
foo.sh
spam

$ GLOBIGNORE='*.sh'

$ rm *

$ ls -1
bar.sh
foo.sh
```

Comment: can i change my command that do the same without run this? `shopt -s extglob`?

Comment: @Tal check my edits..

Comment: thanks :) (stack overflaw make me write 15 character in comment :( :( :( )

Comment: but here there a two good answers!

Comment: @Tal No problem..you can select any one.. Me or A.B. won't mind at all..

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it actually answers the question, while the other one just describes a workaround.

Comment: If you want GLOBIGNORE for only the `rm` command and nothing else, enclose in parentheses and use a semicolon thus: `( GLOBIGNORE='*.sh'; rm * )`

Comment: @PaddyLandau Yeah..i was just showing an example of how it can be done :)

Comment: Highlighting the fact at it has to be **at the start** of the script, I had it in the middle and it was not working

Answer (score 4):

Ok, it's a cross-post, but I have to write an answer. **;)**

You could use `find` instead

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '*.sh' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn `extglob` on:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Comment: @Pilot6: See `man bash`. It enables extended globbing like `!(...)`.

Comment: can i change my command that do the same without run this? `shopt -s extglob`